# TCP from python in docker: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, tcp, plc

For a project, I am communicating with a PLC via TCP, which is directly connected using an ethernet cable. I specify the network interface, since a secondary ethernet cable is connected to a router. The docker is ran using `--network host` in the run command. This TCP message is sent around 300 times per hour for around 10 hours a day. It will work fine for days, and suddenly all I get is `[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`.

I'm not sure what causes restoring the connection. The people using this system restart the PC and PLC, disconnect and reconnect cables to get things working again asap. On the PLC side of things, the TCP connection is some standard building block, which leads me to believe my issue is with docker or my code.

```
TCP_IP_Client = '192.168.1.123' 
TCP_PORT_Client = 2000

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str("enp6s0" + '\0').encode('utf-8')) # replace "enp6s0" with the correct interface 
socket.connect((TCP_IP_Client, TCP_PORT_Client))
if some_boolean:
    sent1 = socket.send(lane_id.to_bytes(2, 'little'))
    sent2 = socket.send(delay.to_bytes(2, 'little'))
    sent3 = socket.send(open_lane.to_bytes(2, 'little'))

    total_bytes = sent1 + sent2 + sent3

    socket.close()
```

Comment: Not related, but `str("enp6s0" + '\0').encode('utf-8')` can be simply written `b'enp6s0\0'`.